# pyarrow - changing column data type does not work

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow

I have a pandas table that I read in chunks and append each chunk to the same parquet file.
Now sometimes a column in the chunk is all null for the whole table there is supposed to be a string value.
I tried a couple of thing one is getting the table schema and changing the column type:

```
PARQUET_DTYPES = {
    'user_name': pa.field('user_name', pa.string())
}

def get_table_schema(parquet_table: pa.Table) -> pa.Schema:
    table_schema = parquet_table.schema
    for column_name in table_schema.names:
        if column_name in PARQUET_DTYPES.keys():
            table_schema = table_schema.set(table_schema.get_field_index(column_name), PARQUET_DTYPES.get(column_name))
    return table_schema
```

But for some reason the I get this error:

```
ValueError: Table schema does not match schema used to create file: 
table:
user_name: null
-- schema metadata --
pandas: '{"index_columns": [{"kind": "range", "name": null, "start": 0, "' + 1970 vs. 
file:
user_name: string
```

So I tried using cast like:

```
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(pandas_chunk)
table['user_name'].cast(pa.string())
```

But it seems like the column stay null.
Does someone know why it happens?

How I'm creating my parquet file:

```
        if index == 0:
            table = pa.Table.from_pandas(chunk)
            table_schema = get_table_schema(table)
            pqwriter = pq.ParquetWriter(updated_path, table_schema)
        else:
            table = pa.Table.from_pandas(chunk, schema=table_schema)
        pqwriter.write_table(table)
```

Thanks!

Comment: `get_table_schema`  returns a new schema, but doesn't mofity the schema of the table. You should call `table = table.cast(table_schema)` before writing it to parquet. See https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.Table.html#pyarrow.Table.cast

Comment: Cool thanks! I'll try it. I didn't really liked my solution yours looks more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Did a little workaround
got the schema from the chunk before I got the table
then changed the schema to fit what I want
and read the table with the schema:

```
def get_table(table_schema: pa.Schema, chunk: pd.DataFrame) -> pa.Table:
    for column_name in table_schema.names:
        if column_name in PARQUET_DTYPES.keys():
            table_schema = table_schema.set(table_schema.get_field_index(column_name), PARQUET_DTYPES.get(column_name))
    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(chunk, schema=table_schema)
    return table
```

```
for index, chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv(output_file.path, chunksize=PARQUET_BATCH_SIZE):
        if index == 0:
            table_schema = pa.Schema.from_pandas(chunk)
            table = get_table(table_schema, chunk)
            table_schema = table.schema
            pqwriter = pq.ParquetWriter(updated_path, table_schema)
        else:
            table = pa.Table.from_pandas(chunk, schema=table_schema)
        pqwriter.write_table(table)
```